# AWS Cognito with social login Google, Facebook, Apple and react native

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, google-signin

I'm working currently on the implementation of social login using react-native and aws cognito. For now, it's working well (with or without amplify), but the issue is that I have to open a webview using the cognito hosted UI, which redirect directly to Google / Facebook / Apple. So basically, when the user click on the google signin button, there is a messagethis kind of message "myapp wants to open amazoncognito to connect...". As a user experience, it is quite mediocre, so I am wondering if it is possible to implement a different signin flow so not to redirect to an external url.
I have tried the implemntation with react-native-google-signin, but in that case, I have to use aws federated identities instead of my user pool (typically, the gogole signin retrieve an id token that can be pass to cognito federated identities). So I do not really like that solution...

I don't know exactly the process of signing up with a social login provider but if someone has ever met the issue and found a user friendly way to implement it, I am obviously interested in the solution ! (One option would be to figure out how to use the IdToken generated by Google to sign the user in my Cognito user pool, the other would be to directly use an iframe to open facebook, google, apple, so at least the message would not appear).

Thank you for you help !

Comment: Write a simple piece of information, https://saachitech.medium.com/use-react-native-inappbrowser-reborn-with-federated-cognito-auth-66db7cf6f19d

Comment: Hello @SaachiTech, thank you for your medium post ! I tried the solution and the browser open inside the app but it seems that the phrase 'myapp wants to open cognitoamazon' still appears... It would be ok if it apple / facebook and not cognito because it is weird for the user. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you using InAppBrowser.open or InAppBrowser.openAuth?

Comment: @SaachiTech : InAppBrowser.openAuth

Comment: I think you can go with InAppBrowser.open

Comment: @SaachiTech I am also trying to achieve the very same thing. I am following your solution but facing an issue. 

import awsconfig from "./src/aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

I am very new to react-native. Please excuse me.  How do I configure urlOpener here? Please suggest! Thanks!

Comment: I am adding the oauth configuration in the aws-export.js. And then configure Amplify in the App.js with the awsconfig (aws-exports.js) imported.

Comment: I could make the required changes but now I get this error:
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_utils.RNInAppBrowser.isAvailable')]

I am using Expo. @SaachiTech

Comment: @PuneetPandey I am not sure if expo support it.

Comment: @SaachiTech It seems it doesn't! Expo seems to be the recommended approach all over the net. I am, however, considering ejecting out of Expo because of a few very important libraries not supported in the Expo. This being one of those. Bluetooth, WebRTC are two other important ones not supported.